# select and refresh an iframe not knowing the id or name

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

is there a way to select and refresh an iframe, not knowing his id or name, and also doing it from inside the same iframe?

the problem is that knowing if the iframe needs to be refreshed is on a response from the server on the iframe.

so, how can i force a refresh on this iframe?

i have found ays to refresh an iframe but all of them require the id like:

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').src = document.getElementById('iframeid').src
```

or

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

also there are more than 1 iframe on the web page and they are loaded dinamicaly into a jquery tab.

i can use jquery or js

Comment: Well, which one do you want to target? The second one? The one with a particular class name, or attribute? You should show some HTML markup.

Comment: "to be refreshed is on a response from the server on the iframe" not possible for cross domain iframes. This of course doesn't apply if iframes are on same domain as main page

Comment: *response from the server on the iframe* means that the page inside the iframe is getting a server response. In that case you just need to refresh the page which is in that iframe? Write code in that page to refresh itself when it receives a response.

Comment: If you don't know what the target is, how do you intend to refresh it? For that matter how do you intend to find out what needs to be refreshed and when?

Comment: @RGraham thats the problem, the one that gets the refresh order, no extra info

Comment: @A. Wolff all iframes came from same domain

Answer (score 0):

if several iframes are in the same container, and you don't know in which order they are loaded, then I don't think you can target one of them.

If there's only one per container and you know the container's id, then you can do

```
jQuery('iframe','#container').attr('src',url);
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you select a single iframe element without knowing any of its identity.
The only information probably is the tagName.

To refresh iframe elements, try this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe')).forEach(function(element){
 element.src = element.src;
})
```

Change the selectors query as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create this function in parent window/page in which iframe will be loaded.

```
function reload(){
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].src = elems[i].src;
        }
    }
```

Call parent.reload() from iframe to reload itself.

But this script will reload every iframe in the page because no specific id or name is available in your case.

if it is available then use,

```
function reload(){
        var elems = document.getElementsById("iframe_id");
        elems.src = elems.src;
    }
```